# awk: using getline - suppress print message for user input to print to terminal only and not to output file

Tags: awk

This may be an easy solve but I can't seem to get. Using an awk script, I am trying to insert a 2-digit code at the beginning of each record that the user is prompted for WITHOUT printing the user message itself to the newfile. An example of the input file:

```
cat datafile1                 
V12309012548458631659
V34509012548458683659
V45709012548458672659
```

...desired output is:

```
cat datafile2
57 V12309012548458631659
57 V34509012548458683659
57 V45709012548458672659
```

but actual output is:

```
cat datafile2
enter agency id:
57 V12309012548458631659
57 V34509012548458683659
57 V45709012548458672659
```

How do i suppress printing of the "enter agency id:" message in the new datafile2 to include the relevant data records only?

NOTE:  I am running it as ***executable file*** invoked as follows: "./interactive.awk datafile1 > datafile2".

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f 
    BEGIN{
        print "enter agency id:";getline agy_id<"/dev/tty"} 
    {  
        print agy_id" "$1;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for nextfile:

```
$ cat file1
V12309012548458631659
V34509012548458683659
V45709012548458672659

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "enter agency id: " | "cat>&2"} NR==FNR{agy_id=$0; nextfile} {print agy_id, $0}' - file1 > file2
enter agency id: 57

$ cat file2
57 V12309012548458631659
57 V34509012548458683659
57 V45709012548458672659
```

With other awks, using getline would be the simplest approach if you want to do it all in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "enter agency id: " | "cat>&2"; getline agy_id < "-"} {print agy_id, $0}' file1 > file2
enter agency id: 57

$ cat file2
57 V12309012548458631659
57 V34509012548458683659
57 V45709012548458672659
```

but in reality I'd just use shell to read the agy_id:

```
printf "enter agency id: "
read agy_id
awk -v agy_id="$agy_id" '{print agy_id, $0}' file1 > file2
```

Don't use shebangs to call awk from shell scripts, it just takes away your ability to use the shell and awk appropriately for zero benefit.

Comment: +1 Always a joy to read your posts/answers. I always end up learning something new! Thank you!

Comment: ended up using shell. used
    printf "Enter Agency ID: " > "/dev/tty"
to redirect message so as to print to terminal and not to file. 
@jaypal am looking into upgrade with admins.
sincere thanks!

Comment: Where do you think the output of printf would go if you didn't direct it to /dev/tty?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

```
$ cat datafile1 
V12309012548458631659
V34509012548458683659
V45709012548458672659
```

```
$ cat script.awk 
BEGIN {
        printf "Enter Id: " ;  getline id < "-"
}
{
        print id, $1 > ARGV[2]
}
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk datafile1 datafile2
Enter Id: 100
```

```
$ cat datafile2 
100 V12309012548458631659
100 V34509012548458683659
100 V45709012548458672659
```

Comment: **Note:** `NF` and `1` is used to _preserve_ blank lines (as shown in your input data). If you don't have them in your file then you don't need them.

Comment: Sorry, one important point I left out. I am running as executable file as follows ./intractv2.awk datafile1 > datafile2. When run from the command line the message is not written to the newfile as you demonstrated. Aside: actually, there are no blank lines in input data(not sure why data pasted that way)

Comment: @user3334019:  please edit your question to show your complete use-case. Good luck t all.

Comment: @jaypal ran as suggested. But seems using ARGV[2] created a loop writing same 3 records, without the ID at beginning, over and over again. File size 123956499 before finally cancelling it!

Comment: @user3334019 Are you running the script exactly like I showed above? What OS are you using?

Comment: @jaypal Yes, exactly as above. OS is 
    uname -a

Comment: @jaypal Yes, exactly as above. OS is 
    uname -a
    AIX pkbppdb11 3 5 00C8527F4C00

Comment: @Ed Morton trying to stick with awk, but i ran a variable substitution test below which gives similar loop.

        >cat substvar.sh

        `variable=test 
        print "shell var" $variable
        awk -v var="$variable" '{print "awk var " var}'`

prints "shell var test" using shell variable and "awk var test" using awk substitution var BUT for every Enter key thereafter. Any idea why? Expecting for it to print shell var once and awk var substitution only once.

    > ./awkparam.sh  
    shell var test  
    awk var test  
    awk var test  
    awk var test

Comment: @user3334019 Use `nawk` or `gawk`. Looks like you are using an old broken version of `awk`.

Comment: @jaypal i see we are running Aug 10 2009 version of awk here at work! so, ARGV feature must not be available with it. but i have used getline for example "date  +'%y%m%d%S'"|getline dt which i read somewhere is only available with nawk and gawk. how do i upgrade?

Comment: @user3334019 You can check with System Administrators if they can upgrade to the latest version.